# Facebook permission missed: read_stream

Tags: java, facebook

I am having some problems with read_stream permission on facebook. Apparently about 10% of the users in my system registers their Facebook account but don't have the read_stream permission. I am always adding that permission to the oauth request.

Anybody else is having this issue? Only happens for some requests and I am not able to reproduce it adding my account.

Could it be some specific configuration in the facebook account?

I am using this library restfb 1.6.9

Comment: What do your app insights say? Are you sure users just aren't declining to provide that (very powerful) permission?

Comment: We have thousands of users registered. The only way I see to loose that permission is by manually removing it. I think it is really improbable that 13000 users did that (10% of our facebook users)